# How to delete a Windows 7/10 backup period via command?

Tags: windows-10, backup

I'm running Windows 7 backup on a Windows 10 PC.  In "Manage Windows Backup disk space" GUI I can see multiple "Backup Periods" and optionally can delete individual periods.  However, if I run `wbadmin get versions` I can see only the most recent backup.

Is there a command to view and delete individual backup periods?

Comment: Why are you running Windows 7 Backup on a Windows 10 PC?

Comment: To back it up.  Windows 10 "backup" doeasn't backup the entire PC.  Presumably that's why Microsoft included Windows 7 backup with Windows 10?